# Smart Client failed when connecting to Hazelcast K8s Cluster with service being exposed using NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I created by cluster using the following commands:

```bash
HAZELCAST_VERSION=latest
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/master/rbac.yaml
kubectl create service nodeport hz-hazelcast-0 --tcp=5701:5701 --node-port=31001
kubectl run hz-hazelcast-0 --image=hazelcast/hazelcast:$HAZELCAST_VERSION --port=5701 -l "app=hz-hazelcast-0,role=hazelcast"
kubectl create service nodeport hz-hazelcast-1 --tcp=5701:5701 --node-port=31002
kubectl run hz-hazelcast-1 --image=hazelcast/hazelcast:$HAZELCAST_VERSION --port=5701 -l "app=hz-hazelcast-1,role=hazelcast"
kubectl create service nodeport hz-hazelcast --tcp=5701:5701 --node-port=31000 -o yaml --dry-run=client | kubectl set selector --local -f - "role=hazelcast" -o yaml | kubectl create -f -
```

And for my python client, I enabled the `use_public_ip` and `smart_routing` arguments. With the Smart Client, client can successfully discover hazelcast members but fail to set up the connection.

```py
    hz_client = hz.HazelcastClient(
        cluster_name="dev",
        cluster_members=["10.xx.xx.xx:31001", "10.xx.xx.xx:31002"],
        use_public_ip=True,
        smart_routing=True,
        client_name='hz.client_0',
        lifecycle_listeners=[
            lambda state: print("Lifecycle event >>>", state),
        ],
        # connection_timeout=120
    )
```

```
DEBUG:hazelcast.reactor:Starting Reactor Thread
INFO:hazelcast.lifecycle:HazelcastClient 5.1 is STARTING
Lifecycle event >>> STARTING
INFO:hazelcast.lifecycle:HazelcastClient 5.1 is STARTED
Lifecycle event >>> STARTED
INFO:hazelcast.connection:Trying to connect to Address(host=10.xx.xx.xx, port=31001)
DEBUG:hazelcast.reactor:Connected to Address(host=10.xx.xx.xx, port=31001)
INFO:hazelcast.lifecycle:HazelcastClient 5.1 is CONNECTED
Lifecycle event >>> CONNECTED
INFO:hazelcast.connection:Authenticated with server Address(host=10.244.1.41, port=5701):b711733c-1a61-49da-8220-3a1fcfe41322, server version: 5.1.1, local address: Address(host=10.xx.xx.xx, port=42818)
DEBUG:hazelcast.cluster:Resetting the member list version
DEBUG:hazelcast.cluster:Handling new snapshot with membership version: 2, member string: 

Members [2] {
        Member [10.244.1.41]:5701 - b711733c-1a61-49da-8220-3a1fcfe41322
        Member [10.244.1.42]:5701 - e0ad91b4-bc8f-4118-9170-9e8b3c28947b
}

INFO:hazelcast.cluster:

Members [2] {
        Member [10.244.1.41]:5701 - b711733c-1a61-49da-8220-3a1fcfe41322
        Member [10.244.1.42]:5701 - e0ad91b4-bc8f-4118-9170-9e8b3c28947b
}

DEBUG:hazelcast.partition:Handling new partition table with version: 1
DEBUG:hazelcast.partition:Partition view event coming from a new connection. Old: None, new: Connection(id=0, live=True, remote_address=Address(host=10.244.1.41, port=5701))
INFO:hazelcast.connection:Connection(id=1, live=False, remote_address=None) closed. Reason: Connection timed out
DEBUG:hazelcast.connection:Destroying Connection(id=1, live=False, remote_address=None), but it has no remote address, hence nothing is removed from the connection dictionary
DEBUG:hazelcast.invocation:Got exception for request OutboundMessage(message_type=256, correlation_id=3, retryable=True), error: TargetDisconnectedError
INFO:hazelcast.client:Client started
DEBUG:hazelcast.invocation:Client is not connected to target: e0ad91b4-bc8f-4118-9170-9e8b3c28947b
DEBUG:hazelcast.invocation:Client is not connected to target: e0ad91b4-bc8f-4118-9170-9e8b3c28947b
DEBUG:hazelcast.invocation:Client is not connected to target: e0ad91b4-bc8f-4118-9170-9e8b3c28947b
INFO:hazelcast.connection:Connection(id=2, live=False, remote_address=None) closed. Reason: Connection timed out
DEBUG:hazelcast.connection:Destroying Connection(id=2, live=False, remote_address=None), but it has no remote address, hence nothing is removed from the connection dictionary
DEBUG:hazelcast.invocation:Got exception for request OutboundMessage(message_type=256, correlation_id=8, retryable=True), error: TargetDisconnectedError
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the `kubectl get service` command? Each service should have an external IP assigned to it so that the members can inform the client about the their public addresses and the client can connect to them using that address.

From the logs you shared, it seems like the members are not aware of their public addresses and that causes client to use the private addresses, which will fail, as you have experienced.

Comment: NodePort service doesn't provide the ExternalIP.